# Backend TCA: possible to make a field nullable?

Tags: typo3, nullable, extbase

I need a backend field where users can enter a time (ie "23:13:46", hours, minutes, seconds). But it should also be possible to not enter a time at all (which should of course be different from 00:00:00). Is it possible to make a field nullable?

What I have so far is this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_something_domain_model_delivery'] = array(
    'columns' => array(     
        'deadline' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Deadline',
            'config' => array(
                'dbType' => 'time',
                'type' => 'input',
            ),
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

But if I enter nothing in the Deadline field, it stores "00:00:00" to the database. The database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_something_domain_model_delivery` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deadline` time DEFAULT NULL,
  ... 
);
```

so deadline is nullable, but I don't know how to achieve this.

BTW: I'm a newbie at typo3, so if you think the way I create the field is retarded or there is a much better way, I'd be thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

First: You are creating the field exactly in the intended way :-)

Second: You need to use the [`eval`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html#eval) property in the configuration of the field. Add the setting `null` to it. Your config should then look like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_something_domain_model_delivery'] = array(
    'columns' => array(     
        'deadline' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Deadline',
            'config' => array(
                'dbType' => 'time',
                'type' => 'input',
                'eval' => 'null',
            ),
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

There are more settings for the `eval` setting that might be of interest to you.

Comment: I tried that, but when I leave the field empty, it still writes "00:00:00" to the database for some reason. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you get "00:00:00" inserted, it is due to SQL field which have default value ""00:00:00". You can check that in ext_tables.sql, you will have default value, and because of that you see it.